# Getting 8 digit watersheds for USA

Tags: shapefile, data, vector, united-states, watershed

Is there an alternative source for 8-digit (vector shapefiles) US watersheds?

The USDA link is down and they are not responsive to my query for getting the data:

https://gdg.sc.egov.usda.gov/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking at this dataset myself today, I opted to send an e-mail and the data layers that I needed. I'll see if they hold true to the 1-2 business days.

However, I also came across this site - http://130.179.67.140/dataset/usgs-huc-10-watershed-layer

Which contains the 8-digit HUCs you are looking for both in shapefile and KML format.

Answer (score 4):

The [National Hydrography Dataset](https://nhd.usgs.gov/) contains the [Watershed Boundary Dataset](https://nhd.usgs.gov/wbd.html), which contains 8-digit watersheds (also 2,4,6,10,12,14, and 16-digit where available) for every state in the USA. The high-resolution version is available for download by state here: ftp://nhdftp.usgs.gov/DataSets/Staged/States/FileGDB/HighResolution/.

Answer (score 0):

For me, links in the both answers are unreachable or broken.

Currently available watershed shapefiles are in the following link:

https://nrcs.app.box.com/v/huc/folder/18546994164